# How to disable rmmod for my own written kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If a user process is working with kernel module, I want that another process can't fire rmmod for that module.
How to achieve this type of functionality?

-beginner in Linux kernel programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rmmod` can *only* unload a module when the refcount is zero.

If the reference count is incremented when a user process is connected (and decremented when it disconnects), you'll be fine.

If the module exposes a device, or is mounted as a filesystem, this should be handled naturally - if not, I guess it'll depend on the userspace interface, but this where to start looking.

By the way, `lsmod` will show your module refcount.  You can check whether it's incremented when the userspace process connects.

Comment: Is used By column number same as refcount?

Comment: Yes, `Used by` shows the refcount as well as the list of modules referencing it (the list may be empty even with a nonzero count, especially for filesystem modules which have a reference per mount).

Comment: Thanks. GET_USE_COUNT(module)