# How to prevent my own LKM to be unloaded by even the root account?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Is there any way to prevent my own LKM to be unloaded even by the root once the LKM loaded successfully?
//DAUM

Comment: Make it built-in? What do you need this for?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291314/how-to-disable-rmmod-for-my-own-written-kernel-module you may just increment use counter (refcounter), and it will be harder for root to remove the module.

Comment: @osgx: Yes, but not impossible. `rmmod -f` can unload such modules although it is not recommended to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think root has all rights on running system.
Therefor root user can delete,add,modify anything.
So you cannot do that